# Unexpected identifier in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm coding a Discord bot in Discord.js v13, and this is my slash command handler:

```
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const  { promisify } = require("util");
const { glob } = require("glob");
const PG = promisify(glob);
const Ascii = require("ascii-table");
/**
 * @param { Client } client
 */

module.exports = async(client => {
    const Table = new Ascii("Commands loaded");

    CommandsArray = [];

    (await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
        const command = require(file);

        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
        CommandsArray.push(command);

        await Table.addRow(command.name, " SUCCESSFUL");
    });
    console.log(Table.toString());
});
```

However when I run it, I get this error (line 15):

```
(await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`)).map(async (file) => {
       ^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)      
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Gabriel-User\Desktop\Discord Bots\adventurecraft-bot\index.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
```

Any ideas on what I could do to improve my code?

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to await `PG`, it has no where to go so you have to assign it to a variable and then use that later on to get your desired outcome.

```
const someVariable = await PG(`${process.cwd()}/Commands/*/*.js`).map(async (file) => {
    const command = require(file);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    CommandsArray.push(command);

    await Table.addRow(command.name, " SUCCESSFUL");
});
```